# Extracting certain substring from a string

Tags: javascript

I want to extract the last part of this string : "https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198364464404".Just the numbers after '/profiles'.But the problem is the URL can change sometimes.

There are two types of url

1.First one is "https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198364464404" with "/profiles" and then the "id"(id is the numbers after '/profiles').

2."https://steamcommunity.com/id/purotexnuk".Second is this type.Where "/profiles" doesn't exist.

I have come up this code :

```
let inc;
const index = 27;
const string = 'https://steamcommunity.com/id/purotexnuk';
if (string.includes('profiles')) {
    inc = 9;
} else {
    inc = 3;
}

console.log(string.slice(index + inc, -1));
```

The above code checks wheather the string "/profiles" is present.If the string contains "/profiles".inc will be 9.So that slice starts from the right side of the string(url) and ends at the first '/' from the right.inc is 9 becuase "profiles/" length is 9.Similar way if the string(url) contains "id".The slice will start from the end and stop at the first '/' from the right.inc will be 3 becuase "id/" length is 3.

The index is always constant because ,"/profiles" or "/id" only occurs after "https://steamcommunity.com" whose length is 27.Is there any better way i can extract only the profile id or profile name?

(profile id - 76561198364464404)

(profile name - purotexnuk )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex for this, it will also take care if your url ends with `/` or has query parameters example `https://steamcommunity.com/id/purotexnuk?ref=abc`

```
/.*(?:profiles|id)\/([a-z0-9]+)[\/?]?/i
```

example:

```js
const regex = /.*(?:profiles|id)\/([a-z0-9]+)[\/?]?/i;
const matches = regex.exec('https://steamcommunity.com/id/purotexnuk');
console.log(matches[1]);
```

Comment: This works whatever is in the URL.This is more dependable Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string with delimiter `/` and return the last value value from the array;

```js
function getNum(str) {
  const arr = str.split('/');
  if (!isNaN(arr[arr.length - 1])) {
    return arr[arr.length - 1];
  }
  return ' no number ';
}

const st1 = "https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198364464404";
const st2 = "https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198364464404";
const st3 = "https://steamcommunity.com/id/purotexnuk";

console.log(getNum(st1));
console.log(getNum(st2));
console.log(getNum(st3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Or do it in one line:

```js
const string = 'https://steamcommunity.com/id/purotexnuk';
console.log(string.slice(string.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, string.length));
```

Comment: this is better answer.

Comment: @Clutch Prince Yes this is the most optimal way,Because for any url the id or the profile name occurs after the last '/'.Perfect Thank you really appriciate your help.